# Stay on top windows

Tags: applications, window-manager

Is there any app which allow any windows (safari / Text edit) to remain on top, even in full screen ?

From what I search, afloat used to be a good solution but with random result.

Comment: My app NoteFlow lets you keep text on top ([download from the Mac App Store](https://appstore.com/Noteflow—onenoteforlife)) and the browser app helium lets you do the same with browser windows.